# Configuring Tomcat 8.5. in Eclipse for running Rest API

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat8

I am getting error while starting apache Tomcat 8.5.8 as a server in Eclipse. It was showing error that installed Tomcat version is 8.5.8 but it is expecting 8.0, below is error:
 [error while configuring Apache tomcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHyp2.png)

After looking in to other threads I came to know about solution for changing the server file at path catalina.jar\org\apache\catalina\util\Serverinfo.properties
Till here I done the change but while saving and came out of RAR file it shows error [Error while saving the changes in serverinfo.properties file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrRHR.png)

I have tried after stoping the tomcat but still it not allow me to save the changes in server file. Please advice.

Comment: Before you go tweaking files manually, did you add it as an 8.5 server or an 8.0 server? Which version of *Eclipse* is this?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting saving the file is because Tomcat is still running, and it has the jar file open.  Windows will not allow you to save changes to a file while some other process has the file open.

First, stop Tomcat, then make your changes to the file and save the jar, and then restart Tomcat.

If it matters, I ran into the same problem with Eclipse incorrectly determining the version of Tomcat.  The solution was to change that "server.info" property in the given file.  For instance, if the Tomcat version you have is 8.5.8, you have to change the version to 8.0.5.8.

Comment: Very true and I came to know about this when I resolve my eclipse update issue(in my another query on same day). I have made the Tomcat setting as Automatic in Services so whenever my system starts Tomcat starts.

Comment: (that's why server.info file is not updated). I have change it to Manual because I need to build every time when I need to run my new Rest API program. But one issue I am facing the tomcat doesn't show my refreshed code changed unless I restart the Eclipse. I am saving the change but still after restarting the Tomcat it shows the old change but not the new change of my REST program. I am missing something here don't know what.